# I have a java.sql.Date value which is giving different hashCode for the same value. why?

Tags: java

I have a java.sql.Date value which is giving different hashCode for the same value. why ?

The date used to set the key to hashmap

```
System.out.println("setting :"+ resultObj.getTmsTrxSqlDate());

System.out.println("date hascode :"+ resultObj.getTmsTrxSqlDate().hashCode());

 

[8/26/21 10:31:38:249 AST] 000000b9 SystemOut     O setting :2021-07-26

[8/26/21 10:31:38:250 AST] 000000b9 SystemOut     O date hascode :-545804806
```

Using the same value to retrieve , it’s a different hashcode and returns  null.

```
System.out.println("@@ 2: "+trxUniqueIdObj.getTrxDate());

System.out.println("@@ date hascode 2: "+trxUniqueIdObj.getTrxDate().hashCode());

[8/26/21 10:31:55:957 AST] 000000b9 SystemOut     O @@ 2: 2021-07-26

[8/26/21 10:31:55:957 AST] 000000b9 SystemOut     O @@ date hascode 2: -535004806
```

Comment: Maybe edit the question, and post your code?

Comment: What do you mean by same Date? Would you please share your code? Because Date class has time also.

Comment: as @GauravJeswani mentioned, you are not displaying the time.

Comment: You shouldn't really be using `Date` anymore.

Comment: A different hashcode is fine, provided `dateA.equals(dateB);` is false. Even if they have the same toString output.